# How to add cookies to a drag and drop div

Tags: html, save, savestate, cookiestore

Hello i have added a drop and drop feature to my site [See Here](http://www.extremehomepages.com/Hompage/4test/) and as i am a beginner i don't know anything about adding cookies to a page or a div, i would like to have a save button which will save the position of the div so that when a user returns to a page it will be where they left it, any help will be appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're using jQuery.

Include [jquery.cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/raw/master/jquery.cookie.js). You can now set cookies like `$.cookie('position_x', 123)` and get them like `$.cookie('position_x')`.

The drag-and-drop library should have some callback that is run when you stop dragging. In that callback, save the x and y position away in separate cookies (to keep things simple).

When the page loads, check for those cookies and use the values to position the element.

Comment: Thanks Henrik N for replying to my post, i have the cookie.js in my code, would you be able to give me an example using my code please thanks.